# useswr crashes react component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

After adding an SWR data fetch to my react component it crashes, if I comment it out it works fine.
I get the following error after uncommenting line `` const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher) ``

```js
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The component

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json())

export default function ViewCounter({
  slug,
  addView = false,
}: {
  slug: string
  addView?: boolean
}) {
  const { data } = useSWR(`/api/views/${slug}`, fetcher)
  // const viewCount = new Number(data?.total)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ViewCounter useEffect', slug, addView)
    const registerView = () =>
      fetch(`/api/views/${slug}`, {
        method: 'POST',
      })

    if (addView) {
      registerView()
    }

  }, [slug])

  // return `${viewCount > 0 ? viewCount.toLocaleString() : '–––'} views`
  return (
    <span className="flex items-center gap-1">
      {data && data?.total}
    </span>
  )
}
```

Maybe it also has something to do with the fact that this component is included within another component that uses getStaticPaths and getStaticProps?

The full codebase can be found here: https://github.com/SennR-1952135/sennr

Comment: Try and see what `data` is.

Comment: The returned data has the following format: ```{"total":42}``` @kellys

Comment: It's probably your fetch, not your swr use (try to replace your fetch for a promise and tell us if it's the problem). Please check if you need the first slash used in your key, sometimes it's in your base URL like `BASE_URL=foo.com/` and then if you add a slash in your key it'll be like `foo.com//api`

Comment: The problem seemed to be with the version of swr, i had to use 1.1.2 or lower, still dont know the exact reason but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the version of swr, i had to use 1.1.2 or lower, still dont know the exact reason but it works.

Comment: Hey, did you find out if there is a better solution for this?
This also solved my issue, but it's weird that there are a lot of other versions and we're not a lot having this issue...